# I want to manage multiple transactions within one function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am looking for a mechanism to manage multiple transactions with Spring Boot.
Here is the code:

```
class Controller {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

class Service {
    @ Transactional
    public void execute () {
        // 1. select process using Repository
        // 2. Update process using Repository
        // 3. select process using Repository
```

If an exception occurs in step 3, you need to rollback the update in step 2.
Up to now I have been processing one database, so it worked without problems with the above.
However, different DBs are used for select and update. (DataSource is different)
For each DataSource, you can deal with the function by splitting it, but in that case the modification of the existing logic will be large.
As mentioned above, there is a way to let Spring manage the transaction while doing all the processing with execute?

Currently it is under investigation whether it can be realized by the following method, but if there is a smarter method, it will be helpful if you let me know.
1. Open multiple Connections with your own annotation (@Transactional2)
2. The Interceptor picks up that the save* function of the Repository has been executed, switches the DataSource

thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the example supplied, the only transaction that you will need to rollback is the one linked to the update statement. In this case, it will be enough to mark the `execute` method as `@transactional`, making sure that you specify that the transaction is linked to the `datasource` that you are updating:

```
class Service {

    @ Transactional("updating-datasource")
    public void execute () {
        // 1. select process using Repository
        // 2. Update process using Repository
        // 3. select process using Repository
```

Any exceptions that occur as a result of the selects, will mark this transaction as `rollback-only` and the update will be rolled back.